# MySQL query incomplete output

Tags: mysql

I am trying to solve this question below but my output on shows sale qty equals to 1 and not including the One unit item as well. What am i doing wrong?

Report those items for which the clothes department has had only one sale for only one unit of the item.

Here is my code

```
SELECT qitem.itemname, qsale.saleqty from qitem
JOIN qsale = 1
ON qitem.itemname = qsale.itemname
Where saleqty=1
And exists( select*from qsale
WHERE qitem.itemname=qsale.itemname);
```

Thank you!

Comment: `JOIN qsale = 1` is not valid syntax.

Comment: You don't need to join and also use `AND EXISTS`.

Comment: "only one sale" means you need to use `COUNT()`.

Comment: It's not possible to give a definitive answer to this question, without sample data and expected output, and with only a malformed SQL statement, we're only guessing. Consider providing example of the data. If you really want help, consider setting up a http://sqlfiddle.com/ demonstration

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `COUNT(*)` to get the count of sales.

```
SELECT qitem.itemname
FROM qitem
JOIN qsale ON qitem.itemname = qsale.itemname
GROUP BY qitem.itemname
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 AND MAX(qsale.saleqty) = 1
```

Comment: Thank you @Barmar it worked! Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.I am still finding my bearing in mysql that's why my syntax are a little confusing. Thank again!